# Magento Adding Address Attributes To The Checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have used this brilliant website to build my own Magento module with an extra customer address field; http://silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator

Ive created a new customer address attribute called 'mycarmake'.  I can see, edit and save the attribute in the admin panel, no problem.

However Im having more trouble adding it to the checkout.  Ive added this field to app/design/default/TEMPLATE_NAME/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml  but it wont save to the customer address record - can someone give me a pointer as to why it's not working?

```
<!-- add fields here -->
<li class="fields">
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:mycarmake"><?php echo $this->__('My Car Make') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" id="billing[mycarmake]" name="billing[mycarmake]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getMycarmake()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('My Car Make') ?>" class="input-text" />
</div>
</div>
</li>
<!-- end add fields here -->
```

I have also added this to the etc/config.xml of my module;

```
</resources>

<fieldsets>
        <sales_copy_order_billing_address>
            <mycarmake><to_order>*</to_order></mycarmake>
        </sales_copy_order_billing_address>
        <sales_copy_order_shipping_address>
            <mycarmake><to_order>*</to_order></mycarmake>
        </sales_copy_order_shipping_address>
        <sales_convert_quote_address>
            <mycarmake><to_order_address>*</to_order_address><to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address></mycarmake>
        </sales_convert_quote_address>
        <sales_convert_order_address>
            <mycarmake><to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address></mycarmake>
        </sales_convert_order_address>
        <customer_address>
            <mycarmake><to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address></mycarmake>
        </customer_address>
        <checkout_onepage_billing>
            <mycarmake><to_customer>*</to_customer></mycarmake>
        </checkout_onepage_billing>
    </fieldsets>
```

Comment: Thanks for this link! I will try to do the same like you and I'll tell something ( Omg 2013 :S )

Comment: You can also add custom attributes in checkout by using a third party extension, here is the one - http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-additional-checkout-attributes-fields.html

Answer (score 0):

**Admin > Customers > Attributes > Manage Customer Address Attribute**

View your **mycarmake** attribute and ensure **Show on Frontend** is set to `Yes`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - I cant find an admin option for customer attributes - where abouts is that?

Comment: This feature is only in enterprise I think